# Calling objects and keys from lookup table

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to append the parent directory's name into filename based on a `0` or `1` value and fileextension **stored in a lookup table**?

- inside the CWD, find all dirs that end with `=camID`, then:
- if `append_dir_to_filename` is `0`: do nothing
- if `append_dir_to_filename` is `1`: then:
- inside `camID` dir **recursively** find all files ending with `raw_file` extension listed for the `camID`, then:
- prefix 1 level parent dir name to all `raw_file` filename
- Exception: do **not** prefix dir name for those `raw_files` that are in `camID` dir (i.e, not in a `camID` subdir).

Filenames **before** and **after**:

```
CWD                                      
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /aaa/ .nef,.jpg,.avi,.wav
    02_camdirxyz=g7                     
          /bbb/ddd/ .cr2,.jpg,.mp4
    03_camdire012345=g7                  
          /yyy/kkk/xxx/ .mp4,.jpg,.avi,.thm
    04_camdire012345                     
          / .mp4,.jpg,.avi

CWD                                      
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /aaa/aaa_.nef, aaa_.jpg, aaa_.avi, .wav            #appended raw files
    02_camdirxyz=so                      
          /bbb/ddd/.cr2,.jpg,.mp4                            #not appended, 'append_dir_to_filename'] = 0 
    03_camdire012345=a9                  
          /yyy/kkk/xxx/ xxx_.mp4, xxx_.jpg, xxx_.avi, .thm   #appended raw files
    04_camdire012345                     
          /.mp4,.jpg,.avi                                    #do not appended, dir not in lookup,
```

**Code** (Works perfectly well if the lookup table has a **different** structure [objects first, then keys], but I need to change to the lookup table structure below.

```
cameraDirs = [os.path.join(cwd, x) for x in next(os.walk(cwd))[1] if x[-2:] in config['append_dir_to_filename']]
    for cameraDir in cameraDirs:
        cameraShortName = cameraDir[-2:]
        for rootDir, _, files in os.walk(cameraDir):
            prefix = os.path.basename(rootDir)
            for file in files:
                if (any(x for x in config[cameraShortName] if file.endswith(x)) and prefix[-2:] not in config['append_dir_to_filename']):
                    os.rename(os.path.join(rootDir, file), os.path.join(rootDir, "{}_{}".format(prefix, file)))
```

Lookup table:

```
config = {
    'g7': {},
    'd5': {},
    'so': {},
}

       #g7, d5, so  called "camID"

config['g7']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1          #set to 1, append dir name
config['g7']['raw_file'] = ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')    #files to append

config['d5']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1          #set to 1, append dir name
config['d5']['raw_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')    #files to append

config['so']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 0          #set to 0, do not append dir name
config['so']['raw_file'] = ('mp4', 'jpg', 'avi')    #files to append
```

In other words, I want to append the directory name for **select** photo and video filetypes (but not for other filetypes) from **select** cameras (but not from all cameras). The info in respect of which files and which cameras to append is in a lookup table.

**For example** (sorting media files from memory cards of different camera types):  If  a directory is ending with ...`=d5` (or whatever else is in the lookup table), then, per the lookup table, all `raw_file` (`nef, jpg, avi`) filenames **within** the ...`=d5` directory are to be appended with 1 level parent directory name like `dirname_origfilename.nef`. If `['append_dir_to_filename'] = 0`, then do NOT append the directory name. One exception: if the files located immediately in the directory ending with ...`=d5` (or `=g7`, or `=so`..), then do not append.

Comment: This question is very confusing. I *think* you're doing some kind of file renaming, but to be honest I'm not sure, since you never explain. Can you add a paragraph or two explaining what you're trying to do at a high level, and maybe say what's wrong with your current code? Can you give an example of the directory structure and the before and after versions of the filenames you want to handle?

Comment: Added the input and output tree.

Comment: FYI, the code I posted **works very nicely**.  The problem, that code has been written for a **different** lookup table (objects first, keys second configuration). All I am trying to do is to update this code so it gets the values from the lookup table I posted.